# Highcharts network-graph show more lines on marker

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to write more info inside a square "marker", something like this image:

[paint-edited](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pirx.png)

Like:

| NODE | NODE1 |
| --- | --- |
| Volt | 230 |
| Current | 10 |
| Size | 120 |

I check highcharts api but I can't get any clear.

How can I do?

Here the code:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph',
    marginTop: 80
  },
   
  plotOptions: {
    networkgraph: {
      keys: ['from', 'to'],
      layoutAlgorithm: {
        enableSimulation: true,
        integration: 'verlet',
        linkLength: 100
      }
    }
  },  
  series: [{
    marker: {
      radius: 13,
      symbol:'square'
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      linkFormat: '',
      allowOverlap: true,style: {
                    textOutline: false 
                }
    },
    data: [
      ['NODE1', 'SLAVE12'],
      ['NODE1', 'SLAVE11'],   
    ],
    nodes: [{
        id: 'NODE1',
        marker: {
          radius: 30,
        },         
      },  
      ]
  }]
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `dataLabelo.formatter` callback which allows returning whatever you want. You can also try to combine it with the `useHTML` feature.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cut92k5n/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.dataLabels.formatter

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph.dataLabels.useHTML